# Highcharts chart not loading after AJAX call to insert partial containing chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, highcharts

I have rails doing a link_to ajax call from a menu to dynamically insert a chart into the main content area of my site. I can see the html is replaced correctly.. but the chart doesn't isn't loaded.

Here is the main content part of my application.html.erb:

```
<div id="maincontentcontainer">
    <div id="maincontent">
        <div class="section group">
            <div class="col span_1_of_7">
                <%= render :partial => "shared/menu" %>
            </div>
            <div id="replace">
                <%= yield %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the index html after the AJAX call that inserts the below partial:

```
<div id="replace">
  <div class="col span_6_of_7">
    <section id="infographic">
      <div id="infographicContent">
        <div id="chart" style="min-width: 310px; height: 700px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
      </div>
    </section>  
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the partial:

```
<div class="col span_6_of_7">
    <section id="infographic">
        <div id ="infographicContent">
            <%= javascript_include_tag "highcharts" %>
            <%= javascript_include_tag "charts" %>
            <div id="chart" style="min-width: 310px; height: 700px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
        </div>
    </section>  
</div>
```

My chart.js has all the chart has options (called options) that is passed in and run like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#chart').highcharts(options);
    });
});
```

Can anyone explain to me why? And what I need to do about?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are calling `$('#chart').highcharts(options);` *before* the ajax finished. So, it won't find the `<div id="chart">` that wasn't inserted yet.

---

To resolve that issue, you have two options:

1. Move the chart creation script to the ajax *callback*, to execute *after* ajax completion:

> ```
>  $.get('domain.com/ajax_call?param=value').then(function(response) {
>       $("#replace").html(response);
>       $('#chart').highcharts(options);
>  });
> ```

2. Move the chart creation script to the response html *after* the insertion of `<div id="chart">`:

> ```
> <div class="col span_6_of_7">
>     <section id="infographic">
>         <div id ="infographicContent">
>             <%= javascript_include_tag "highcharts" %>
>             <%= javascript_include_tag "charts" %>
>             <div id="chart" style="min-width: 310px; height: 700px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
>             <script>$('#chart').highcharts(options);</script>
>         </div>
>     </section>  
> </div>
> ```

---

<sub>**Note:** I am assuming that the additional `});` in your code was just a question typo/mistake.</sub>